# ln alias path to audio samples not recognized by Ableton Live

Tags: mac, audio, terminal, alias, ableton-live

I used to have an external HDD titled "WD Elements 250GB" which contained audio samples I used in Ableton Live projects.

The files are still present, though on an internal HDD now. I tried creating an alias, so Ableton can still use those file paths.

```bash
cd /Volumes
sudo mkdir "WD Elements 250GB"
sudo ln -s /Volumes/IRONWOLF1/SoundsFromMars/ /Volumes/WD\ Elements\ 250GB/"
```

even though the alias works in terminal, Ableton won't know what do to and just reports the files as missing.

Does the alias need some special flag or user rights so Ableton knows how to handle it?

Comment: Any clues? I know the description might be not very straight forward, but help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ableton will assume the samples are all in the same place they originated from until you show it exactly where they are. Click the "files are missing" tab that shows up red, then select the folder they are in, and "replace automatically" I believe it is. Ableton should recognize the files by waveform and replace with all your edits intact.